# The Joint pdf of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

2. Let the joint density of X and Y be given by
   $f(x,y)= 24xy$ for $0< x < 1, 0 < y < 1, 0 < x+y <1$
   and zero otherwise. Are X and Y independent?

   Let us compute the marginals. For $x ∈ (0, 1)$ we have $0<y<1−x$. Therefore,
   $f (x, y)
   = 0$ unless $0<y<1-x$.

   Therefore, we do not have $f(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y (y)$ that for all $x,y$ and hence X and Y are not independent.

However, my question is where does the $1-x$ and $1-y$ come from, when you are solving this questions. (it is placed above the integral)

Answer (score 0):

The support of the function is: $0<x<1, 0<y<1, \underbrace{0<x+y<1}_{\implies y<1-x}$

This is equivalent to: $x\in (0,1), y\in (0,1-x)$

It's inside the triangle formed by the x axis, the y axis, and the line $y=1-x$

Thus: $f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{1-x} f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname d y$

Also: $f_Y(y) = \int_{0}^{1-y} f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname d x$